# how to pass hour, minute and second in calendar object in android java

Tags: java, android, calendar

i have made an application in which i need to perform date conversion.
Here is my code.

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
            c.set(2011, 04, 29,0,0,0);
            String cdate = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", c.getTime());
            Log.i(tag,cdate);
```

now when i check my LOG here is the output:

04-22 12:44:15.956: INFO/GridCellAdapter(30248): 2011-04-29 HH:00:00

why is the hour field not getting set. i have explicitly passed 0 when i was making the calendar object, still it is display HH in the LOG.
what could be the problem?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

use lower-case hh:

```
String cdate = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", c.getTime());
```

Comment: such a simple solution. it worked.... when i checked on android website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) they have used HH..... don't know what is happeining.

Comment: hh means its a 12 hour clock, HH means its a 24 hour clock. i need the result in 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

set `c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0)` and it should work.
Have you tried like this?

```
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,4);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2011 , 4 , 29 )                             // Represent April 29, 2011.
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) // Determine the first moment of the day. Often 00:00:00 but not always.
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) // Generate a String representing the value of this date, using standard ISO 8601 format.
                                   .replace( "T" , " " )  // Replace the `T` in the middle of standard ISO 8601 format with a space for readability.
```

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

If you are trying to get the first moment of the day, do not assume the time 00:00:00. Anomalies in some time zones mean the day may start at another time-of-day such as 01:00:00.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You want a specific date in your Question.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2011 , 4 , 29 ) ;
```

Apply the time zone again in determining the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z );  // Determine the first moment of the day on this date for this zone.
```

I recommend always including an indicator of the time zone or offset-from-UTC with your date-time strings. But if you insist, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` predefined in java.time that does not include zone/offset: [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). Merely remove the `T` from the middle.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
                   .replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).