# How to convert milliseconds to Greenwich Mean Time

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How do I convert time in milliseconds for example : 1384248606000

To the following format `dd/MM/yyyy 24hourtimeformat GMT +timezoneoffset`?

How would the dateformat for the following function look?

```
public static String getFormattedDate(long time, DateFormatType type) {
    String dateFormat = DateFormatType.getDateFormat(type);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format(dateFormat, cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Greenwich? GMT?

Comment: In defense of OP's misspelling: the pronunciation of "Greenwich" is far closer to "Grinich" than it is to "Greenwich"

Comment: I think he meant "Grinch Mean Time".  It happens towards the end of December :-)

Comment: is there an answer please ?

Comment: Read the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @JBNizet I already did that, the date format i put is : dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz and the result is the time is always in 12 hour format, regardless of the fact that hh by the javadoct says it is for 24 hour format

Comment: Then re-read the doc, because you misread it. It says: *h: Hour in am/pm (1-12); H: Hour in day (0-23)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290138/2136812

String cdate = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", c.getTime());

for some reason i should have put "kk" instead of "hh" or "HH" and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try H for 24 hour format

final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

Comment: the result for this one is : 2013/11/21 HH:11:26 GMT+02:00

Answer (score 0):

A millisecond is the real value of time, independent of timezone, and calendar. The String you want is a presentation of that time.

So you shall use a calendar, a TimeZone (the default value is your OS's TimeZone which is not GMT) and a SimpleDateFormat.

Assign proper GMT timezone to the calendar, and the calendar to SimpleDateFormat. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for SimpleDateFormat in Java 1.7 states clearly:

> The following pattern letters are defined (all other characters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved):

```
    Letter      Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
    ...          
    H           Hour in day (0-23)      Number          0
    ...
```

And it says the same in the Java 5.0 ... which is the earliest version that is still readily accessible.

If this is doesn't work for you then either you are using some weird / ancient / non-compliant version of Java ... or your program is incorrect.  Perhaps you have used a homoglyph for the Latin H character in your source code; see http://homoglyphs.net/