# Display Date in 24-hour issue

Tags: android, datetime, android-date

I am working simple app where I can get current `DateTime` and convert that into `24-hour` format.

### Code:

```
  String DATE_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

  String DATE_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss  = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";  
  

  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    
  tv.append("\n in 12-hour format: "+getDateFormatted(bootDate));
    
  tv.append("\n in 24-hour format: "+getDateFormatted2(bootDate));

  public String getDateFormatted(Date date){
    return String.valueOf(DateFormat.format(DATE_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss, date));
}

public String getDateFormatted2(Date date){
    return String.valueOf(DateFormat.format(DATE_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss, date));
}
```

### Problem:

It's perfectly working in my devices `Samsung Galaxy S3(Android 4.3), S4(Android 4.3) and Nexus 5(Android 4.4)`. while the same code I am running in `Huawei Ascend Y330 device(Android 4.2.2)` it's not display properly.

### Screenshot in Samsung Galaxy S3, S4 and Nexus 5:

[image]

### Screenshot in Huawei Ascend Y330:

[image]

So, what is the problem actually? I don't understand. Is it android system issue? or device issue?

Any idea anyone.

Comment: Do you have this issue only with Huawei Ascend Y330?

Comment: Did you try using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of DateFormat (like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755073/24-hour-clock-not-working-in-dateformat-android?answertab=active#tab-top) explained) ?

Comment: @Skizo Only in `Huawei Ascend Y330` particular device while it's perfect working in all other 5 devices

Comment: @heRoy Ok wait let me try...

Comment: Try using `SimpleDateFormat` as @heRoy said, and let us know if it worked, if it didn't probalby it's a device issue...

Comment: @heRoy It's working fine with `SimpleDateFormat`. thanx budy. I supposed already try.Please post it with some answer. So other people able to know that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755073/24-hour-clock-not-working-in-dateformat-android?answertab=active#tab-top) suggested to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of DateFormat. For more explanation about the differences between these two classes, you could take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529521/what-is-the-difference-between-android-text-format-dateformat-and-java-text-date/27116266#27116266).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) `SimpleDateFormat` can handle the 'H' for 24h format but `DateFormat` needs 'k'.

> Use a literal 'H' (for compatibility with SimpleDateFormat and
>   Unicode) or 'k' (for compatibility with Android releases up to and
>   including Jelly Bean MR-1) instead. Note that the two are
>   incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.append("\n in 12-hour format: " +sdf);
tv.append("\n in 24 -hour format: " +sdf2);
```

Comment: @MD I didn't know @heRoy has already told you in the comment to use `SimpleDateFormat` otherwise i wouldn't post the answer. May be was writing an answer that time.

Answer (score 0):

This works in all the devices,

```
static final SimpleDateFormat IN_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
static final SimpleDateFormat OUT_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma", Locale.US);

/**
 * To format the time.
 *
 * @param strDate The input date in HH:mm:ss format.
 * @return The output date in hh:mma format.
 */
private String formatTime(String strDate) {
    try {
        Date date = IN_DATE_FORMAT.parse(strDate);
        return OUT_DATE_FORMAT.format(date);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

use the method : `formatTime(YOUR_TIME)`