# I'm using DateFormat (MMM dd H:mm) to get Jan 29 9:27 this result ,samsung S2 device showing (Jan 29 H:27) result ,It should return hour not H

Tags: android, date-format, date-formatting

```
if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this.context))
{
sB.append(DateFormat.format("MMM dd  h:mm a", callingDate));
}
else {
sB.append(DateFormat.format("MMM dd  H:mm", callingDate));
}
```

In first condition it is showing expected result **(Jan 29 9:27)** ,but in second condition it is showing **(Jan 29 H:27)**  result ,why it is showing capital H instead of hour in only Samsung S2 device.

I have tested in other samsung device like s3, s4 ,s5 it is showing expected result , please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

suggested to use `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `DateFormat`. So [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755073/24-hour-clock-not-working-in-dateformat-android?answertab=active#tab-top) and [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559224/display-date-in-24-hour-issue/28559595#28559595)

Answer (score 0):

Plz coorect the api's as below :

```
if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this.context))
{
sB.append(DateFormat.format("MM dd  hh:mm a", callingDate));
}
else {
sB.append(DateFormat.format("MM dd  HH:mm", callingDate));
}
```

Comment: I tried all these things already now it is showing (Jan 29 HH:27).